# Is there a way to combine a dropdown <select> menu with a text field?

Tags: javascript, text, drop-down-menu

Good afternoon Stackoverflow folks,

I have the following javascript code, and I want to add prior to every "member" text field a dropdown select menu defined by an array.
Both values from the select and text should be saved with the pattern select ( element : member )after in one single structured data value in mySQL.
The feature in the code of first defining the number of members should stay as it is.

I already tried with javascript to define a second document.createElementById:

```
var array = ["menu1","menu2","menu3"];
var selectList = document.createElement("select");
selectList.setAttribute("id", "mySelect");
```

but it didnt seem to work.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function addFields(){
        var number = document.getElementById("member").value;
        var container = document.getElementById("container");
        while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
        container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
        }
        for (i=0;i<number;i++){
            container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Member " + (i+1)));
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.type = "text";
            input.name = "member" + i;
            container.appendChild(input);
            container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
        }
    }
</script>
<body>
        <input type="text" id="member" name="member" value="">Number of members: (max. 10)<br/>
        <a href="#" id="filldetails" onclick="addFields()">FillDetails</a>
        <div id="container"/>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

The code can tested hier http://jsfiddle.net/t656N/1/

The result i am willing to achieve is something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHkZi.jpg

Comment: had you have a look to [`datalist`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist)?

Comment: yes sure. but how would I implement datalist into my function addFields()? The dropdown list with the text filed should be available after I run the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working using a second for and a createElement as shown below:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function addFields() {
  var number = document.getElementById("member").value;
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  var optionsSelect = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Option 1'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'Option 2'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: 'Option 3'
    }
  ];

  while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
    container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
  }
  for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    var select = document.createElement('select');
    for (var j = 0; j < optionsSelect.length; j++) {
      var options = document.createElement("option");
      options.value = optionsSelect[j].id;
      options.text = optionsSelect[j].title;
      select.appendChild(options);
    }
    container.appendChild(select);
    container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" -> Description " + (i + 1) + " "));
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "text";
    container.appendChild(input);
    container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
  }
}
</script>
```